# How do I keep the left div aligned to the top?

Tags: html, css

I have these divs.

[image]

The html is the following.

```
<div id="full-size">
    <div id="left-content">

    </div>
    <div id="center-content">

    </div>
    <div id="right-content">

    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS of the four divs:

```
#full-size{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    top:5px;
    position:relative; 
    padding: 1px 220px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;

    background-color:#F00;
}
#left-content {
    width:190px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;         
    background-color:#222;  
    margin-left: -200px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:table-cell;
}
#center-content {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;  
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;       
    background-color:#222;
    padding:5px;
    display:table-cell;    
}
#right-content {
    width:190px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
    float:right;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#222;
    margin-right: -200px;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:#222;
    position: absolute; /*newly added*/
    right: 220px; /*newly added*/
    top: 5px;/*newly added*/
}
```

Every thing is responsive exactly like i want. The left and right divs have fized size and position, the center div must always adapt to the width beteween the border divs.

What i cant figure out, its why the left div always stays on the bottom, i need it to be always on top like the right one.

This is my problem, getting the left div to stay on top. I don't understand that much about css, but these ones are the ones i managed to make that work in Firefox, Chrome and IE. In all of them the layout is the same.

As i said i dont understand that much about css, and the only thing i want is this layout to work in most browsers. I dont mind to throw it all away if i need to. I only need something working.

UPDATE:

Looks like these work just fine if isolated, so here is all the stuff and the error is happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/wr0r8msu/1/

**This only happens in Firefox, IE and Chrome are working!**

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: From the image, it looks like the left div is aligned to the bottom. Here is a fiddle of the provided code http://jsfiddle.net/wr0r8msu/

Comment: yes it's the left, my bad :P, the fiddle example works there but not here :X

Comment: ok so the problem must not be here, must be the rest of the css, im gonna put the all code in Fiddle and that shows whats happening - http://jsfiddle.net/wr0r8msu/1/

Comment: There is a bunch of duplicate properties in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use position: relative; instead of position: absolute; when using float, maybe that will fix your problem ;-)

Comment: i dropped the position absolute from the right-content div and it works fine.

Comment: i made a mistake, its not the right one, its the left one i want to put up. If i drop de position, both of them go to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I modified your css a bit.

```
 #full-size{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    top:5px;

    padding: 1px 220px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;

    background-color:#F00;
}
#left-content {
    width:190px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;         
    background-color:#222;  
    margin-left: -200px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:table-cell;
}
#center-content {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid #000;

    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;       
    background-color:#222;
    padding:5px;
    display:table-cell;    
}
#right-content {
    width:190px;
    border:1px solid #000;

    float:right;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#222;
    margin-right: -200px;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:#222;


}
```

it does work without fixed or relatively positioned divs.

Comment: are you trying to make this a responsive design?

Comment: Just read teh question <p> Every thing is responsive exactly like i want. The left and right divs have fized size and position, the center div must always adapt to the width beteween the border divs.</p>

Comment: yes, this is desktop version. Your css puts them both in the bottom :(

Comment: i just ran my css and it worked for me :-( what browser are you running it in?

Comment: im in Firefox, just tried Chrome and IE and both are working, assume you have one of these?

Comment: yes and i noticed that in fiddle you have more code than you posted. Did the code i gave you work in chrome and IE?

Comment: noup, it must been the last time i was working on this, i might had fixed it and forgotten, sorry =(

Comment: try using position relative on right-content div i believe someone else had suggested this

Comment: both go to bottom if i change that